# How do I add to a wstring?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

This works with std::string

```
std::string class::something(char* input) {
    std::string s(input);
    s = "hai! " + s;
    return s;
}
```

But fails if I try the same thing with wstring

```
std::wstring class::something(wchar_t* input) {
    std::wstring s(input);
    s = "hai! " + s;
    return s;
}
```

How do I do the same thing with std::wstring?

Comment: wstring `append` and `+=` also works, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928968/trying-to-append-a-wstring

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem here is types. A wstring isn't a string, but a quoted string constant is related to it (it is generally a `const char*`), so

```
s = "hai! " + s;
```

is actually a problem.

The value `"hai! "` is of type `const char*`, not type `const wchar_t*`. Since `const char*` is a basic type, it's searching for a global `operator+` that operates `const char*` and `wstring`, which doesn't exist. It would find one for `const wchar_t*` and `wstring`, because [`std::basic_string<T>`, the template underyling type for both `string` and `wstring`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) (using `char` and `wchar_t` as the type parameter, respectively) also creates template methods for `operator+ (const T*& s1, const basic_string<T> s2)` so that addition can work.

Therefore, you need to make "hai! " a wstring:

```
std::wstring class::something(wchar_t* input){
    std::wstring s(input);
    s = L"hai! " + s;
    return s;
}
```

The `L` prefix on a string constant, in Visual C++, defines it to be "long", and therefore a wstring. `wstring` [is actually `basic_string<wchar_t>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3s3k55(v=VS.80).aspx), which is, because of the behavior of C++ templates, a completely different type from `basic_string<char>` (a `std::string`), so you can't combine the two.

Comment: "The value "hai! " is of type std::string...," is an incorrect statement.  The actual type is `char const*`.  "The L prefix on a string constant, in Visual C++, defines it to be "long", and therefore a wstring," is also incorrect in three ways.  First, it's not specific to VC++.  Second, it defines it to be "wide", not "long".  Third, it's not a wstring, it's a `wchar_t const*`.

Comment: Quite correct. I realized this while you were writing the comment and was editing my answer at the same time. Although I thought it was a const wchar_t const*, not just a wchar_t const*? Which I inaccurately wrote as const wchar_t*, missing the second const, but I'm not sure I want to edit it again to correct that, now that I'm only sort of wrong rather than flagrantly wrong.

Answer (score 9):

You use a wide character literal instead of a char character literal by prefixing "hai!" with L.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of having 2 versions of the code (1 for wide and 1 for multi-byte):

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
    typedef std::wstring tstring;
    typedef wchar_t tchar;
#   define TEXT(s) L##s
#else
    typedef std::string tstring;
    typedef char tchar;
#   define TEXT(s) s
#endif

tstring class::something(tchar* input) 
{
    tstring s(input);
    s = TEXT("hai! ") + s;
    return s;
}
```

This prevents having to rewriting code when you change your compiler string encoding compiler options.

Comment: `typedef std::wstream tstring;` wstream should be wstring, shouldnt it? Also adding yet another Macro for strings is not recommended - in VS TEXT already exists, so this would even produce a compiler warning if common libraries like ATL/MFC are used in the project (or added later). I'd rather recommend a templated function.