# Trying to append a wstring

Tags: c++

I am trying to append an integer to wstring:

```
TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH]={0};
GetModuleFileName(NULL, buffer, sizeof(buffer)/sizeof(*buffer));
TCHAR* fileName = PathFindFileName(buffer);
std::wstring name(fileName);

std::wstring temp;   
temp = _wgetenv(L"TEMP");
temp.append(L"\\-deploy-temp-");
temp.append(rand()); <-- gives an error; can't convert it to wstring
temp.append(L"\\");
temp.append(name);
```

Thank you in advance.

Here what I've attempted:

```
std::wstring to_wstring(rand());
```

Apparently, this is supposed to work in C++11, but I have MSVC2010, so I don't think it compiles on my setup.

Comment: "so I won't ever have to touch C++ again" what?

Comment: "so I won't ever have to touch C++ again" - sounds a bit offensive.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: I'm writing one simple C++ application for a specific purpose and that is the only application I'll write in C++. (I'm not a programmer; this is a hobby)

Comment: Then pay someone to write it for you. We are helping people *learn* here.

Comment: @KirilKirov: No offense intended. :|

Comment: Okay, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: C++ is really powerful lang, spend some time to learn it, i promise you will enjoy development in C++!

Comment: @user2264410 - don't give up like this and "Okay, sorry for wasting your time", just remove that words and try to show, that you really want to understand why this is not working.

Comment: C++ is a very sharp tool, making it both powerful but also complicated and dangerous. The is no "a little C++", either you learn it or you don't, and learning it means using it for several hours every day for a year. If you can't invest that time, you will write bad code and create more problems than you solve, which causes frustration. I don't blame you for wanting to get rid of it, even though I use it myself and enjoy doing so. Use a less sharp tool, that will allow you to be more productive though. My personal preference is Python, but other scripting languages are not worse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

// ...
std::wstring wstr;

std::wstringstream wss;
wss << rand();

wstr.append( wss.str() );

std::wcout << wstr;
//...
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks! Didn't know you can use stream to convert.

Comment: @user2264410 - you're welcome. And next time, you should be more careful what you write in the questions :) See, the down-votes are reverted and you got your answer. Good luck :)

Comment: BTW: Instead of using append(), you can use += to append to a string: `wstring s; s += L"foo"; s += "bar";`.

Comment: @doomster - true. I used `append` just because it was already used in the code. I prefer `operator+=`, too.